# Show content on button click then hide that button

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and I have an Iframe game that I want to prevent this game from running until the button (play game) is clicked.

So I want to create a div area (something like a button) when it is clicked the game will display, and that div area disappear.

Here is the code that I use:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('.playbutton').on('click',function(e){e.preventDefault();
 var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
 if($('#playgame').attr("onClick")==undefined){
 $('#playgame').css("display","none");
 }
    $('#game').css("display","block");
    jQuery.ajax({
 url:'my_site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
 type:'post',
 data:{action:'display_game',post_id:post_id},
 success:function(response){
 $("#game").html(response);
 }});});});
```

```css
#playgame {
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
    .playbutton {
    height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #353535;
    }
    p.playnowtext {
    font-size: 55px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffc402;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #bashabasha {
    padding: 70px 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playgame"> 
    <div class="playbutton" data-id="<? echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
    <p class="playnowtext">Play Game</p></div> </div>
    <div id="game">
    <!--?php echo get_game( $post->ID );?-->
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, there something wrong, as the div area appear with the css but when I click on play game, nothing happen. The div area still there and didn't disappear nor the game starts to run.

I know that there is something wrong on the Javascript code, but I don't know it.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're missing `});` at the end of your `<script>` block.

Comment: ^^ this. did you have a look at the console? There for sure was an error!

Comment: Yes, that right. But this didn't solve the issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are sending an API request which is a `post` request, what is the response of that request ?

Comment: OK, I discovered that I didn't put google jquery.min.js file. Now the every thing worked but still the game is running behind the button while I put e.preventDefault(); I think the issue is on var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, from your description I tried to implement it without the API response, I used dummy text here ( you can use your response here ).

By default the div or the button whatever you want will remain shown, and the game area will be hidden by css, once you get the response from the API call, you put the contents in that `#game` element and show it with `.show()` method.

Check if the code snippet makes sense to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.playbutton').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_id = $(this).data('id');

        if (typeof ($('#playgame').attr("onClick")) === 'undefined') {
            $('#playgame').css("display", "none");
            console.log('no id found')
        }
        $('#game').css("display", "block");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'my_site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'display_game', post_id: post_id
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#game").html(response).show(); // add .show() to show the '#game' element;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#playgame {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}
.playbutton {
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #353535;
}
p.playnowtext {
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffc402;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#bashabasha {
  padding: 70px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#game {
  display: none; /* as this is hidden by default and will be shown by javascript */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="playgame">
    <div class="playbutton" data-id="<? echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
        <p class="playnowtext">Play Game</p>
    </div> 
</div>
<div id="game">
    <!--?php echo get_game( $post->ID );?-->
    <!-- let's assume we get our expected contents here through the API request and the bellow content is that  -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <!-- And these are hidden by default -->
    <?php 
    if ( function_exists( 'get_game' ) ){
      echo get_game( $post->ID ); 
    }
    ?>     
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfect, but there is only one issue is that the game is still running behind the button and <div id="game"> should be empty as the button is not clicked but it shows the game code so the game is running on behind. I think that preventdefault(); is not working here.

Comment: It's hard to say what kind of game is that, is there any other controls to pause the game or it starts to run immediately after it's loaded, what tech is used for coding that game and a lot more.
Some information would help to point out the issue.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the role function(e) {e.preventDefault(); here. What should it prevent exactly here?

Comment: It's actually for preventing the default click event on an element like `<a>`, nothing to do with your code or prevent your function, for example, when you click on an `anchor` you should be navigated to another page, but you want to make something else happen ( run a function ), then you use this thing to prevent the default click ( which redirects you to another page ) and do your defined action ( or function ) 
You can read more about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: Also, you can try removing that prevetdefault from your code and see what happens

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks alot for this info. But please bear with me: Now I need to not run the game function unless the button is clicked, I mean the div game should be empty like this <div id="game"></div> only unless the button is clicked, so then the div game will come with the game code. Here the code again: <div id="playgame"> <div class="playbutton" data-id="<? echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><p class="playnowtext">Play Game</p></div> </div>
<div id="game">
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'get_game' ) )
 echo get_game( $post->ID );
}
?>
</div>

Comment: I have no idea what your php code returns, so can't be so sure about it.
but there is one thing you can do, put the entire `JS` function within the `php` `if` condition, so that the `script` will only be executed when your php condition evaluates to true

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#playgame').click(function() {
  $('#playgame, #game').toggle();
});
```

And CSS:

```
#game {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: this would make it easier, yes, but doesn't address the OPs main problem. Neither can he get the `post_id` now.